# Questions about length converter im making

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have to do this as an assignement:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuBIu.png

here is the code (Shoutout dream cap for helping me massively)

```js
    function pvc(val){
      var input = document.getElementById("value").value;
      var result = document.getElementById("result");

      if (val == 'inch') {  
        result.innerHTML = input / 0.39370;
      } else if (val == 'cm') { 
        result.innerHTML = input * 0.39370;
      } else if (val == 'celc') {   
        result.innerHTML = * 9 / 5 + 32
      } else if (val == 'fahr') {   
        result.innerHTML = (farenheit – 32) * 5 / 9 
      }
    }
```

```html
    Valeur:<input type="text" id="value" name="valeur" value="0" > <p id="result">Resultat ici</p>
    <button type="button" id="inchToCm" onclick="pvc('inch')">Pouces vers cm</button>
    <button type="button" id="cmtoInch" onclick="pvc('cm')">CM vers pouces</button>
    <button type="button"id="celciusToFarenheit" onclick="pvc('celc')">Celcius vers
    Farenheit</button>
        <button type="button" id="farenheitToCelcius" onclick="pvc('fahr')">Farenheit vers Celcius</button>
```

It just returns nothing when I test it with any number on the webpage, im guessing theres something wrong with the return result.

Comment: Check the console for syntax errors.

Comment: Do you understand the error ? Because I really dont .. ive been on this for an hour lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem comes from syntax errors in your code, first this line :

```
result.innerHTML = * 9 / 5 +32
```

You probably meant to put `input` before it so it becomes :

```
result.innerHTML = input * 9 / 5 +32
```

Secondly this line :

```
result.innerHTML = (farenheit – 32) * 5 / 9
```

This line is wrong for two reasons : first the operator should be dash (`-`) not whatever that is(I thought it's an underscore `_` but it's not, I don't know what it is :) ).

Secondly `farenheit` variable isn't defined so you'll get Reference Error, a probable fix would be to use `input` instead.

For the future : you can open your browser's developer tools, If some error is thrown you'll see it in the browser's console, you can also use your browser's debugger capabilities to debug issues like that.

Last but not least you can prevent those kinds of errors before even executing the script by some sort of "static type checker" (e.g. [flow](https://flow.org/)) or a "linter" (e.g. eslint, jslint, jshint).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fixed up version. You have several issues:

- `farenheit` is not a valid variable. Changed to input.
- `-` was also incorrect unicode. (It was a long dash, and threw an exception).
- You had a stray `*` on the `result.innerHTML = * 9 / 5 + 32` line. I'm assuming you want to multiply input by `9 / 5 + 32`.

```js
function pvc(val) {
  var input = document.getElementById("value").value;
  var result = document.getElementById("result");

  if (val == 'inch') {
    result.innerHTML = input / 0.39370;
  } else if (val == 'cm') {
    result.innerHTML = input * 0.39370;
  } else if (val == 'celc') {
    result.innerHTML = input * 9 / 5 + 32;
  } else if (val == 'fahr') {
    result.innerHTML = (input - 32) * 5 / 9;
  }
}
```

```html
Valeur:<input type="text" id="value" name="valeur" value="0">
<p id="result">Resultat ici</p>
<button type="button" id="inchToCm" onclick="pvc('inch')">Pouces vers cm</button>
<button type="button" id="cmtoInch" onclick="pvc('cm')">CM vers pouces</button>
<button type="button" id="celciusToFarenheit" onclick="pvc('celc')">Celcius vers
    Farenheit</button>
<button type="button" id="farenheitToCelcius" onclick="pvc('fahr')">Farenheit vers Celcius</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time all

Comment: The `*` was not stray, it needed `input` in front of it.

Comment: eh im still new to this, idk why i put farenheit as a variable must be tired lol.